# Creating dynamic meta tags using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, metadata

I am trying to figure out how I can create dynamic meta tags, using my mysql database to grab the info.

Right now I have

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="player" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Share your sounds. Sign up with your Twitter account." />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@Gabberus" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="{$title}" />

<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://gabber.us/uploads/media/{$art}" />
<meta name="twitter:player" content="https://gabber.us/embed.php?id={$id}" />
```

Now, the problem that I have. Is the {$title} will set the correct title (song name) but {$id} {$name} and {$art} (id, name, art are the database columns) doesn't grab any info from the database.

I am not experienced in PHP and any input would be great.

Would it be possible to add something like this to my config.php file
$CONF['tplayer'] = 'https://gabber.us/embed.php?id=IDHERE';

so that I can use {$tplayer} in the meta?

If I am completly wrong please let me know, any help is appreciated.

Best,
Jamie

Added: index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('./includes/config.php');
require_once('./includes/skins.php');
require_once('./includes/classes.php');
require_once('info.php');
require_once(getLanguage(null, (!empty($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : $_COOKIE['lang']), null));
$db = new mysqli($CONF['host'], $CONF['user'], $CONF['pass'], $CONF['name']);
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $db->connect_errno . ") " . $db->connect_error;
}
$db->set_charset("utf8");

if(isset($_GET['a']) && isset($action[$_GET['a']])) {
    $page_name = $action[$_GET['a']];
} else {
    $page_name = 'welcome';
}

// Extra class for the content [main and sidebar]
$TMPL['content_class'] = ' content-'.$page_name;

require_once("./sources/{$page_name}.php");

$resultSettings = $db->query(getSettings());
// Added to verify whether the user imported the database or not
if($resultSettings) {
    $settings = $resultSettings->fetch_assoc();
} else {
    echo "Error: ".$db->error;
}

// Store the theme path and theme name into the CONF and TMPL
$TMPL['theme_path'] = $CONF['theme_path'];
$TMPL['theme_name'] = $CONF['theme_name'] = $settings['theme'];
$TMPL['theme_url'] = $CONF['theme_url'] = $CONF['theme_path'].'/'.$CONF['theme_name'];

$TMPL['volume'] = $settings['volume'];
$TMPL['supplied_formats'] = $settings['trackformat'];
$TMPL['site_title'] = $settings['title'];

if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password']) || isset($_COOKIE['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])) {
    $loggedIn = new loggedIn();
    $loggedIn->db = $db;
    $loggedIn->url = $CONF['url'];
    $loggedIn->username = (isset($_SESSION['username'])) ? $_SESSION['username'] : $_COOKIE['username'];
    $loggedIn->password = (isset($_SESSION['password'])) ? $_SESSION['password'] : $_COOKIE['password'];

    $verify = $loggedIn->verify();
}

$TMPL['content'] = PageMain();

if(!empty($verify['username'])) {
    $TMPL['menu'] = menu($verify);
    $TMPL['menu_buttons'] = menuButtons($verify);
    $TMPL['url_menu'] = $CONF['url'].'/index.php?a=stream';
} else {
    $TMPL['menu'] = menu(false);
    $TMPL['menu_buttons'] = menuButtons(false);
    $TMPL['url_menu'] = $CONF['url'].'/index.php?a=welcome';
}

if($settings['captcha']) {
    // Captcha
    $TMPL['captcha'] = '<div class="modal-captcha"><input type="text" name="captcha" placeholder="'.$LNG['captcha'].'"></div>
    <span class="register-captcha" id="captcha-register"><img src="'.$CONF['url'].'/includes/captcha.php" /></span>';
}
if($settings['fbapp']) {
    // Generate a session to prevent CSFR
    $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));

    // Facebook Login Url
    $TMPL['fblogin'] = '<div class="modal-btn modal-btn-facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id='.$settings['fbappid'].'&redirect_uri='.$CONF['url'].'/requests/connect.php?facebook=true&state='.$_SESSION['state'].'&scope=public_profile,email" class="facebook-button">Facebook</a></div>';
}

$TMPL['url'] = $CONF['url'];
$TMPL['year'] = date('Y');
$TMPL['powered_by'] = 'Powered by <a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank">'.$name.'</a>.';
$TMPL['language'] = getLanguage($CONF['url'], null, 1);

$skin = new skin('wrapper');

echo $skin->make();

mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: You show us your template code, that is good. But we don't know how the template obtains the $title. Tell us about it, because it is where the problem is. E.g. we don't know if the data is already extracted from your database. Tell us which CMS you use. Wordpress?

Comment: Hey, PaulH I added the index.php that pulls some info from the database i believe? I am using a php script called phpsound.